# Function returning itself instead of str value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 in conjunction with cfscrape and BeautifulSoup in an attempt to display the baby name of the day as a label. However, the function I am using to grab and return the baby name is returning itself instead of the name. Here is my code:

```
import sys
import cfscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

class Scraper():
    def getNameOfTheDay():
        spider = cfscrape.CloudflareScraper()

        with spider:
            nameData = spider.get("https://www.babynames.com/").content

            soup = BeautifulSoup(nameData, "lxml")
            nameContainer = soup.find("div", {"class": "notd-name"})
            name = nameContainer.text
            return name

class NameScraper(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NameScraper, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Name Scraper")
        self.setFixedSize(644, 591)

        self.nameScraperUI()

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(10)

    def nameScraperUI(self):
        self.nameOfTheDayLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.nameOfTheDayLbl.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 15)
        self.nameOfTheDayLbl.setText("Name of The Day")

        self.scrapeBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.scrapeBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 500, 181, 41))
        self.scrapeBtn.setText("Scrape Names")
        self.scrapeBtn.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.scrapeBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.updateLbl, self.nameOfTheDayLbl, Scraper.getNameOfTheDay))

    def updateLbl(self, label, text):
        label.setText(str(text))

def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = NameScraper()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the need to use partial since you can do the following:

```
    self.scrapeBtn.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.scrapeBtn.clicked.connect(self.updateLbl)

def updateLbl(self):
    self.nameOfTheDayLbl.setText(Scraper.getNameOfTheDay())
```

But if you still want to use partial then you should evaluate the function:

```py
self.scrapeBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.updateLbl, self.nameOfTheDayLbl, Scraper.getNameOfTheDay()))
```

But even so it would generate an error since it needs a parameter so you must use the @staticmethod decorator:

```py
class Scraper():
    @staticmethod
    def getNameOfTheDay():
        # ...
```

With the previous change, a problem still arises: The GUI freezes because the **scraper** task is very time consuming, so to avoid that problem it must be implemented in another thread. Considering all of the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys
import threading

import cfscrape

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class Scraper:
    @staticmethod
    def getNameOfTheDay():
        spider = cfscrape.CloudflareScraper()

        with spider:
            nameData = spider.get("https://www.babynames.com/").content

            soup = BeautifulSoup(nameData, "lxml")
            nameContainer = soup.find("div", {"class": "notd-name"})
            name = nameContainer.text
            return name


class QScraper(QtCore.QObject):
    nameSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self):
        self.nameSignal.emit(Scraper.getNameOfTheDay())


class NameScraper(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NameScraper, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Name Scraper")
        self.setFixedSize(644, 591)

        self.q_scraper = QScraper()

        self.nameScraperUI()

        self.q_scraper.nameSignal.connect(self.nameOfTheDayLbl.setText)

    def nameScraperUI(self):
        self.nameOfTheDayLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.nameOfTheDayLbl.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 15)
        self.nameOfTheDayLbl.setText("Name of The Day")

        self.scrapeBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.scrapeBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 500, 181, 41))
        self.scrapeBtn.setText("Scrape Names")
        self.scrapeBtn.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.scrapeBtn.clicked.connect(self.q_scraper.start)


def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = NameScraper()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```

**Note:** [The @dahanraz solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60942220/6622587) is incorrect since `getNameOfTheDay()` is running when creating the GUI and not when pressing the button.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. If it's not too much to ask, could you explain how pyqtSignal is being used here? I have never seen it before and am having a hard time figuring out what exactly it does.